# Can a hotspot android device intercepts my traffic?

Tags: wi-fi

i'm asking of how can an Android device that i'm connected to its hotspot can intercept all of my traffic or do other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are looking for a technical, or simple response.
The explanation, is that the android (Hotspot) device, acts as a **gateway**, therefore **all traffic is passed on there**. But the content of encrypted traffic (like https) cannot be seen (directly, at least).

This is **different as a normal MITM**, because the traffic route is not being changed. The gateway (or router), downloads the information while it is being sent.
[image: Normal MITM example]

There are a lot of apps that do this, like [zAnti](https://www.zimperium.com/zanti-mobile-penetration-testing). The problem is, normally, to this to be accomplished, root is needed.